# Option to see download speed when downloading updates

Tags: update-manager

How can I see the download speed when I am downloading updates with the Update Manager?

See image:

[image]

Comment: It's not within synaptic, but you could set a divert-sockets rule for matching traffic(check source ip against ubuntu mirror), tee the traffic, and count the bytes passed through to a simple pygtk applet.

Comment: You might want to pull the 12.04 tag since it's still beta

Comment: Post it in brainstorm 
this question may be offtopic here

Comment: @aking1012 - I knew I was having some confusion between windows. It was in Synaptic that I saw the download speed while installing an app. This characteristic is not in Software Center or the Update Manager and as Aboobacker mentioned it would be better in the brainstorm webpage if there is no config file or something that shows this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of(since the functionality is not built in to the update-manager) is to open the system monitor and monitor the download speed at the bottom, this will show the total download speed and how fast those updates are coming as long as update-manager is the only thing using the Internet at that time.

[image]